# Symfony2 : How to make the php_intl extension available for Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, setattribute

I'm trying to follow this documentation on Symfony : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

ok so here is my thing, I've externalised my form and created a specific form class for handling the process and being able to reuse it.

So what happen when I submit the form, whatever the info are okay or not for my class, I get this fatal Error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\wamp\www\QNetworks\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php
>   on line 130 Call Stack

I'm running with php 5.3.9 and my intl extension is installed and activated BUT when I run the app/check.php command I see :

> [[WARNING]] Checking that the intl extension is available: FAILED
>
> *** Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators) ***

So I don't understand what the problem with this extension. Should I reinstall it ? 
When I go here : http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php
I see tht i can install the PECL or the ICU library, but i don't know if I should and if there is any relation with my problem ..

Comment: I had the same problem on wamp server with php version 5.3.8. Fortunately turning off intl extention worked for me. It's workaround rather then solution but it's quick and it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Intl extention must be configured propertly. 
Check on your server if this really activated using phpinfo()

then on your php.ini activate logging:

```
[intl]
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
extension=php_intl.dll
```

and check logs

If it's activated maybe it's a malfunction. Try to redownload the dll into c:\PHP\ext\php_intl.dll

Comment: Thanks, I've finally decided to reinstall wamp with the last version of php and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

take care you have two php.ini :

- *wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
- *wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin

you should uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in both.

Answer (score -2):

After enable intl extension, you need copy some files to apache bin directory. It could help you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtIcpdPzXiE